# Python transform while-loop into a generator function

Tags: python, list, optimization, while-loop, generator

I want to replace and optimize an extensively used while-loop that generates list values from an input list.  How can this be accomplished with iter, itertools, a generator function or something else?  The following example code is for illustration only:

```
thislist = [2, 8, 17, 5, 41, 77, 3, 11]

newlist = []

index = 0
listlength = len(thislist)

while index < listlength:
    value = 0
    while thislist[index] >= 0:
        value += thislist[index]
        value += 2 * value
        index += 1
    value += thislist[index]
    index += 1
    newlist.append(value)

print newlist
```

Comment: Your example code raises an `IndexError: list index out of range`. Probably because you're re-using the same "index" for the inner and the outer.

Comment: And the inner `while` end condition will never be met.

Comment: Basic idea for generators: put it in a function suite (block) and change `output_list.append(value)` to `yield value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a generator. It yields the next value every time you call "next" on it.

```
def my_gen(data):
    for index in range(0, len(data)-1):
        value = data[index]
        value += 2 * value
        #etc
        yield value

my_list = [2, 8, 17, 5, 41, 77, 3, 11]
x = my_gen(my_list)
print x.next()
print x.next()
```